# How to use Do While Loop / While End While Loop in this code instead of GoTo

Tags: vba, goto

I'm a bit new with Visual Basic and I'm trying to make a program that would generate random numbers from 1 to 9 without repetition using arrays. I've also read that instead of using GoTo statements (as they are generally frowned upon), Do While Loop or While End While Statements could be used. I've tried using these loops but have not made it work. Here is the code:

```
Dim x As Integer = 0, y As Integer = 0, num As Integer = 0, arr(8) As Integer
        lstLoop.Items.Clear()
        For x = 0 To 8 
Start:
            Randomize()
            num = Fix(Rnd() * 9) + 1
            For y = 0 To 8
                If num = arr(y) Then
                    GoTo Start
                End If
            Next
        arr(x) = num
        lstLoop.Items.Add(arr(x))
        Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to loop while you have found the number in the array:

```
Sub GenerateRandom()

Dim x As Integer
Dim num As Integer
Dim arr(8) As Integer

Randomize Timer

For x = 0 To 8
    Do
        num = Fix(Rnd() * 9) + 1
    Loop While FindInArray(arr, x - 1, num)

    arr(x) = num
Next x

End Sub

Function FindInArray(arr() As Integer, maxIndex As Integer, num As Integer) As Boolean

Dim i As Integer
FindInArray = False

For i = 0 To maxIndex
    If arr(i) = num Then
        FindInArray = True
        Exit Function
    End If
Next

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

use dictionary.

```
Sub test()
    Dim dic As Object
    Dim n As Integer
    Dim Num As Integer
    Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Do Until n = 9
        num = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 9)
        If dic.Exists(num) Then
        Else
            n = n + 1
            dic.Add num, num
        End If

    Loop
    Range("a1").Resize(1, 9) = dic.Keys
End Sub
```

or

```
Sub test()
    Dim dic As Object
    Dim Num As Integer
    Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Do Until dic.Count = 9
        num = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 9)
        If dic.Exists(num) Then
        Else
            dic.Add num, num
        End If
    Loop
    Range("a1").Resize(1, 9) = dic.Keys
End Sub
```